# Verification Code Issue in PHP Order Confirmation System

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on a PHP-based order confirmation system, and I'm facing an issue with the verification code. The code is successfully generated, sent to the user via email, but when the user enters the code for verification, it's not being recognized as correct.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('location:../connexion.php');
} else {
    require_once '../connectDB.php';

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $commandeId = $_GET['id'];

        $commande = $database->prepare("SELECT produits.idProduit, produits.nomProduit, produits.imageType, produits.image, commandeDetails.Quantite, produits.prixProduit FROM commandeDetails INNER JOIN produits ON commandeDetails.IDProduit = produits.idProduit WHERE IDCommande = :orderID");
        $commande->bindParam(":orderID", $commandeId);
        $commande->execute();

        if ($commande->rowCount() > 0) {
            $emailUser = $_SESSION['user']->email;
            require_once '../mail.php';
            // $verificationCode = 'ddec5800';
            $verificationCode = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8);
            $cmd = $database->prepare("UPDATE commandes SET verificationCode = :verificationCode WHERE idCommande = :commandeId");
            $cmd->bindParam(":verificationCode", $verificationCode);
            $cmd->bindParam(":commandeId", $commandeId);
            // $_SESSION['verification_code'] = $verificationCode;
            $cmd->execute();
            $verifCodeQuery = $database->prepare("SELECT verificationCode FROM commandes WHERE idCommande = :commandeId");
            $verifCodeQuery->bindParam(":commandeId", $commandeId);
            $verifCodeQuery->execute();
            $verificationCode = $verifCodeQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

            $mail->addAddress($emailUser);
            $mail->Subject = "Confirmation de Commande - DRCoffee";
            $mail->Body = '
      
          
              
                  <h1>DRCoffee</h1>
              
              
                  <h2>Confirmation de Commande</h2>
                  <p>Merci de votre commande sur DRCoffee. Utilisez le code de vérification ci-dessous pour confirmer votre commande :</p>
                  <h3>Code de Vérification: ' . $verificationCode . '</h3>
                  <p>Entrez ce code lors du processus de confirmation de commande.</p>
                  <p>Merci de choisir DRCoffee!</p>
                  <p>L\'équipe DRCoffee</p>
              
              
                  <p>DRCoffee - Casablanca, Maroc</p>
              
          
      ';
            $mail->setFrom("oyuncoyt@gmail.com", "DRCoffee");
            $mail->send();
        }

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['verification'])) {
            $verife = $database->prepare('SELECT verificationCode FROM commandes WHERE idCommande = :commandeId');
            $verife->bindParam(":commandeId", $commandeId);
            $verife->execute();
            $code = $verife->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
            if ($_POST['verification_code'] == $code) {
                $updateStock = $database->prepare("UPDATE produits SET stock = stock - :quantitySold WHERE idProduit = :productId");

                while ($commandeDetails = $commande->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $productId = $commandeDetails['idProduit'];
                    $quantitySold = $commandeDetails['Quantite'];

                    $updateStock->bindParam(":quantitySold", $quantitySold);
                    $updateStock->bindParam(":productId", $productId);
                    $updateStock->execute();
                }

                $commande->execute();

                $updateStatus = $database->prepare("UPDATE commandes SET etat = 'Confirmée' WHERE idCommande = :orderId");
                $updateStatus->bindParam(":orderId", $commandeId);
                $updateStatus->execute();

                header('Location: confirmation-success.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                header('Location: about.php');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

1.Verification code is generated and stored in the database.
2.Email is sent to the user with the correct code.
3.your text.User enters the code for verification, but it's not being accepted.

- Are there any potential pitfalls in my verification code logic?
- Is the email content being sent correctly, and could it affect the verification process?
- Any suggestions for debugging this issue to identify where the verification process is failing?

Any help or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

What I've Tried:

1. Checked that the verification code is successfully generated and stored in the database.
2. Verified that the email is being sent to the user with the correct code.
3. Confirmed that the user is entering the code correctly during the verification process.
4. Reviewed the database to ensure that the verification code is correctly fetched for comparison.
5. Checked for any error messages or exceptions during the execution of the verification process.

Expected Outcome:

I expected the user-entered verification code to match the one stored in the database, confirming the order. However, even when entering the correct code, the system does not recognize it as valid.

By providing this information, you give potential helpers on Stack Overflow a clearer understanding of the steps you've taken and the specific issue you're encountering.

Comment: Ignore email for now, just generate a verification code and test it. While debugging, don’t redirect, it can hide errors.

Comment: The form where you let the user input this code, contains a query string parameter named `id` in its `action` URL? Because if not, then `$commandeId`, which you are using to select the verification code from the database, will be empty.

Comment: Next step: debug it line by individual line. Cbroe has probably given you a clue